# What's the fastest way to see if a table has no rows in postgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization, is-empty

I have a bunch of tables that I'm iterating through, and some of them have no rows (i.e. just a table of headers with no data).
ex: `SELECT my_column FROM my_schema.my_table LIMIT 1` returns an empty result set.

What is the absolute fastest way to check that a table is one of these tables with no rows?

I've considered: `SELECT my_column FROM my_schema.my_table LIMIT 1` or `SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_table LIMIT 1`
followed by an `if result is None`(I'm working in Python). Is there any faster way to check?

Answer (score 4):

This is not faster than your solution but returns a boolean regadless:

```
select exists (select 1 from mytable)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select exists (select * from myTab);
```

or

```
select 1 where exists (select * from myTab)
```

or even

```
SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'schema_name.table_name'::regclass;
```

The 3rd example uses the estimator to estimate rows, which may not be 100% accurate, but may be a tad bit faster.

Answer (score -5):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name limit 1;
```

Try this code .

Comment: Depending on the database, that could be very expensive if the table *isn't* empty.

Comment: No it ain't. You limit the result rows to one, but it is only one row anyway. (LIMIT is executed after COUNT).

Comment: Not to be rude, but this may be one of the worst possible answers in terms of speed. I cannot imagine a slower way to get the information requested. I only say this to recommend against anyone seeing this in the future and thinking it's a viable solution when speed is a primary concern-- the limit 1 clause is a red herring and won't affect the results in any way except perhaps a very very small amount of slowdown. You are free to count the rows in the table under certain situations, but it should be avoided when just checking if a row exists as it's about the slowest way to find that.